# Updated Elasticservice on Droplet of Digital Ocean, Elasticsearch will no longer start

Tags: elasticsearch

The error I am receiving when I try to start up elasticsearch

```
-- Unit elasticsearch.service has begun starting up.
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch logstash[1064]: [2020-10-08T23:54:05,137][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch logstash[1064]: [2020-10-08T23:54:05,138][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=76:67:e9:46:24:b8:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=79.124.62.110 DST=206.189.196.214 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=52316 PROTO=
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]: output:
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]: error:
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]: Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:126)
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:88)
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:137)
Oct 08 23:54:05 ElasticSearch systemd-entrypoint[14701]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:95)
```

Comment: Hi Deb, you need to provide more details for people ot help you. E.g: OS, version of elasticsearch (more exactly it seems a ELK combo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a lot like [this reported issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51361#issuecomment-704208369) and [this one](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-wont-start-after-7-9-1-to-7-9-2-upgrade/249878).

In your `jvm.options` file, if you replace this

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

with this

```
8-13:-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
8-13:-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
8-13:-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

it should work again.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you. What does this actually do for jvm options?  So greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I bug you on the next error from logstash? When I check the status of it, it is running, but giving me a:[logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][push to elasticsearch alerts index] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil
Oct 09 12:42:43 ElasticSearch logstash[1064]: [2020-10-09T12:42:43,467][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][push to elasticsearch alerts index] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil
Oct 09 12:42:43 ElasticSearch logstash[1064]: [2020-10-09T12:42:43,467][WARN ][logstash.out

Comment: Do you mind creating a new question, since it's unrelated to this one

Comment: Will do. Thank you.